# How to fix one virtual desktop to my second monitor with KDE?

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, virtualdesktop

I have two monitors on a NVIDIA card. KDE combines the second monitor with TWinView to all my virtual desktops. While this is nice I'd rather had an additional virtual desktop (let's say desktop #5) fixed to my second monitor while switching beetween desktop #1 to #4 on my first monitor.

Can this been done? (KDE 4.8, Ubuntu 11.10)

At the monent I can only use the following workaround: 
drag an application to the second monitor on desktop #1 and apply "fix to all desktops" on the window in question. Then when switching desktops the window shows on all of them but is fixed to a position on the second monitor. While this works it'd be more convenient if I could have an independent desktop on my second monitor with it's own activities; panels and stuff. And when starting an application there it should stay there also ...

I also tried to configure the second monitor as individual X-Server-Dislpay. But then still I can't send running applications over to the second screen ...

Answer (score 9):

This answer is for KDE 4.x. For KDE Plasma 5, check out the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1399798/124466) m0h17.

---

I'm actually running KDE 4.9.4 atop ArchLinux, but it shouldn't matter. Since KDE treats the screen as one (mostly), switching Virtual Desktops will switch them on all screens. However, there's a handy "On all Desktops" button in every window titlebar (near the app logo, you enable/disable that in SystemSettings->WindowDecorations->ConfigureButtons). Click that, and your application will remain there even if you switch the desktops. It's a workaround, but it works.

Comment: thx barraponto, I changed my setup, but now I will try to fix this again with your suggestion. I let you know here whther it woks - thx a lot!, piedro

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Virtual Desktops Only On Primary` script from https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/kwin-scripts

Clone the repo, and run the script.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/kwin-scripts.git
cd kwin-scripts/
./helper.sh install virtual-desktops-only-on-primary
```

After installing the script, go to System Settings > Window Management > KWin Scripts and enable the `Virtual Desktops Only On Primary` script.

[image]

There will be no need to manually set the Window Settings every time.

Comment: This is working great. Thank!